# How to select and add a new item in select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I am pulling my hair off trying to do a very simple thing with select 2.  When I edit a record of table1, I have a simple select dropdown with a list of items built from a field of table1 (with distinct).  Sometimes I need to add a new item.  So I thought that the example to create and add a new item would work but it does not.  When I type the new item in the open box on top of the dropdown, I got "No result found"... ok but how do I force this new item to be selected and recorded in the database (and obviously available for later use)?

I am not really good in JS, so I presume I am doing something wrong or something is missing... please help.

```
<select class="selectAdd-who" name="who">
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2" selected>item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectAdd-who').select2();
    // Set the value, creating a new option if necessary
    if ($('.selectAdd-who').find("option[value='" + data.id + "']").length) {
        $('.selectAdd-who').val(data.id).trigger('change');
    } else { 
        // Create a DOM Option and pre-select by default
        var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, true, true);
        // Append it to the select
        $('.selectAdd-who').append(newOption).trigger('change');
    } 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sure you want to use jquery? It's kinda out of favor nowadays, since vanilla javascript offers most of the query stuff now and there are better frameworks for the rest.

Comment: As I said JS is not my forte.  I do not want to use jquery... just want this select2 to work to add new entry.  Can you help?